# Error can't find of link to hdf5 libary while installing Netcdf 4

Tags: 20.04, bash, system-installation

I'm trying to install Netcdf 4 which supports an air quality model that I will compile after finishing this netcdf installation.

However, I faced the "error: Can't find or link to the hdf5 library" which I found several solutions from your website and others, however, all do not work.

My steps to install include:

```
#install zlib:
tar xvzf zlib-1.2.11.tgz
cd zlib-1.2.11
mkdir /usr/local/zlib-1.2.11
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11
make
make install
#install hdf5
tar xvzf hdf5-1.12.0.tar.gz
cd hdf5-1.12.0
mkdir /usr/local/hdf5-1.12.0
exportLDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11
export FC=gfortran
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/hdf5-1.12.0 --enable-fortran
make
make install
#Install netcdf
tar xvzf netcdf-4.6.2.tar.gz
cd netcdf-4.6.2
mkdir /usr/local/netcdf-4.6.2
export CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/hdf5-1.12.0/include
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/hdf5-1.12.0/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/hdf5-1.12.0/lib/
export FC=gfortran
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/netcdf-4.6.2
```

then faced the error message:

```
"checking for library containing H5Fflush... no
configure: error: Can't find or link to the hdf5 library. Use --disable-netcdf-4, or see config.log for errors."
```

My laptop information is:

```
Static hostname: it-Precision-7520
     Icon name: computer-laptop
       Chassis: laptop
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
        Kernel: Linux 5.11.0-27-generic
  Architecture: x86-64
```

Please advise me what could be the problem? How could I solve it?
Thank you very very much.
Chi

Comment: Which application do you need to compile? How it is named? Where its sources are located?

Comment: CAMx, from website www.CAMx.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not force Ubuntu to be LFS. You should remove all locally installed stuff by using commands below:

```
cd /usr/local/zlib-1.2.11
sudo make uninstall

cd /usr/local/hdf5-1.12.0
sudo make uninstall

cd /usr/local/netcdf-4.6.2
sudo make uninstall
```

And then use official Ubuntu repositories. They provide needed  [zlib](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=zlib.pc), [hdf5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=hdf5%20pc) and [netcdf](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=netcdf.pc&searchon=contents).
So to install all of them you have to open terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libhdf5-dev libnetcdf-dev
```

and then you'll be able to compile any application involving these libraries.

Comment: great. thank you very much. I follow your guideline, and set the path /usr for netcdf path of makefile of my soffware, and it's installed successfully. Thanks